# infrastructure software for developing web service

Tags: java, tomcat, ejb-3.0, apache-axis

I'm developing a web service and as being new to the technology, I did a bit of research on the internet on the infrastructure software/technologies needed. Below are my findings and hope to get your precious opinion:

1. Application Server - Tomcat6
2. Web service engine - Axis2
3. Web service implementation - POJO
4. Accessing Database MySql - JPA (Only 5 simple tables)

Do they look good to you?

I'm thinking of using EJB3 for point3, but there are a lot of people on the internet (and this forum) saying EJB3 is not worth the effort, POJO will do. What's your view?

Thanks,
Sarah

Comment: Hi to the person who voted close, could you please tell me the reason? You could even put it into answer and I'd vote for you, if your arguments make sense.

Comment: The Stack Overflow community typically doesn't like questions calling for opinion-based answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be worth trying on [programmers.stackexchange.com](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) as its not specifically a coding question. For my 2 cents, I'd seriously consider whether you wanted to go down the SOAP route (Axis is SOAP only) or whether you should use REST.

Tomcat is usually a good choice for a server, as is MySQL for a DB. If you're going to use JPA, you need to choose a JPA implementation; the obvious one is Hibernate. If you do choose to use REST then I can recommend Jersey, which is Sun's reference implementation.

Comment: FYI - Axis **does** provide a RESTful interface, so you can support both SOAP and REST and not have to choose between the two, and can keep a single service definition.  http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/rest-ws.html

Comment: Thanks guys. I will try programmers.stackexchange.com